# which datatype for using a time in gorm?

Tags: grails, types, hsqldb

how can i handle a time (like 14:33) during calculations and savings in database? What datatype can i use for this in a HSQL DB?

I want to calculate things like workload or rest time. Is there a built in possibility to convert times to decimals?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for the *time* representation, the most convenient type ought to be [Joda Time's `LocalTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html).
There are several converters available to [map the `LocalTime` type to the database](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/userguide.html#Available_Types).

You need the JAR packages [`joda-time` and `joda-time-hibernate`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/).

Your domain class then might look like this:

```
import org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalTimeAsTime
import org.joda.time.LocalTime

class TimeDomain {
    LocalTime localTime

    static mapping = {
        localTime type: PersistentLocalTimeAsTime
    }

    // business logic would belong to a service class
    LocalTime plusMinutes(int minutes) {
        localTime.plusMinutes(minutes)
    }
}
```